# Popover is not showing content of template

Tags: html, angular, popover, mdbootstrap, ng-template

I try to show a Popover with a template for the content:

```
<a role="button">
        <ng-template #popTemplate>
            <div class="md-form">
                <textarea type="text" id="form7"
                    class="md-textarea md-textarea-auto form-control" mdbInput
                    style="padding-top: 0;">
                </textarea>
                <label for="form7">Kommentar</label>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <i mdbPopover="popTemplate"
            placement="right" mdbPopoverHeader="Dismissible popover" triggers="focus"
            class="far fa-comment fa-sm">
        </i>
    </a>
```

The Problem is, that the Popover will not show the HTML-Content. Instead it shows only the text popTemplate (see attached Printscrren).

Can someone help me, what there can be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Why are you putting the form contents *inside* the button?

Comment: @Andy I tried both variants. This was the last one, that's why it's in the post now.

Comment: Have you tried square brackets, as they did in the examples? “Create a tag, as below, and place [mdbPopover]="popTemplate" inside your <button> tag”

Comment: Like @Andy said, you should use the brackets, otherwise Angular won't look for a variable to fill the Input, instead it will interpret the primitive value.

Comment: I've overlooked. It works with the [ ]. Thank you @Andy